# How to use Accelerometer to measure distance for Android Application Development

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am just a beginner in the application development industry. I know the accelerometer can be used to return the current acceleration along three axis in meters per second squared (m/s2).  But I have come to know that an accelerometer can also be use as speedometer.

I want to know how I can use accelerometer to determine distance traveled by Android device between points of interest. If it is possible, then how can I implement it? I have seen a similar question "how do I measure the distance traveled by an Iphone using accelerometer" [How do I measure the distance traveled by an iPhone using the accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707726/how-do-i-measure-the-distance-traveled-by-an-iphone-using-the-accelerometer). But I didn't come to a point.

Thank You,
Arslan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the velocity using accelerometers only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085583/how-can-i-find-the-velocity-using-accelerometers-only)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You get position by integrating the linear acceleration twice but **the error is horrible. It is useless in practice.**

Here is [an explanation why (Google Tech Talk)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) at 23:20. I highly recommend this video.

Similar questions:

[track small movements of iphone with no GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6158176/341970)
[What is the real world accuracy of phone accelerometers when used for positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027724/341970)
[how to calculate phone's movement in the vertical direction from rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6291110/341970)
[iOS: Movement Precision in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5550453/341970)

Comment: Thank you Ali its of great use

Comment: Is it possible to detect motion and wakeup from sleep ? I have mediatek device which has no "significant motion" sensor (according to sensors detect apk), yet, it has built in feature which turn on screen on movement. How can it be ?

Comment: @ransh Measuring distance is difficult. Detecting movement is easy: You only have to detect that the changes in the output of the sensor is above a pre-configured threshold. You do not need to measure distance to detect movements; it is much much simpler.

Comment: my problem concerns mainly power save. if cpu does not sleep in between sensors event then it's a problem.

Comment: @ransh Please look at the title of this question: "How to use Accelerometer to measure distance for Android Application Development". You only want to detect movements, and you are concerned with power save. What you are asking is a totally different question, and we therefore should not discuss this here in comments. If you have a new question then please post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine it with GPS positioning, and filter data with [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).
GPS give rough but stable position, while accelerometer give more accerate but drifting position.