# How to Get Device is Shaked or not using SensorListener?

Tags: android, android-sensors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: I want to shake it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it)
>   [How to use Accelerometer to measure distance for Android Application Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352681/how-to-use-accelerometer-to-measure-distance-for-android-application-development)
>   [How to Implement SensorListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383723/how-to-implement-sensorlistener)

If Device is not Shaking at that time the Alertdialog is Displayed so how to get the device is shaking or not?

Comment: I'm also very proud of you. You don't have time to research and try things on your own to write a good question, but you have time to push questions like this and complain about people who consider this rude.

Comment: Ok i shouldn't argue about this (but someone is wrong on the internet!!111): Calling people idiots and not beeing rude. Nice claim. Also if you push your questions by creating duplicates you say ""§%$ you, I'm more important" to anyone else who has a question, because you draw attention away from their posts. I find this rude. If you want to get better/faster answers, write a good question and get upvotes. This will lead to quality answers fast.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code for check device is shake or not**

// Need to implement SensorListener

```
public class ShakeActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {
    // For shake motion detection.
    private SensorManager sensorMgr;
    private long lastUpdate = -1;
    private float x, y, z;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 800;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...... // other initializations
    // start motion detection
    sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    if (!accelSupported) {
        // on accelerometer on this device
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
    if (sensorMgr != null) {
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMgr = null;
        }
    super.onPause();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // only allow one update every 100ms.
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) &gt; 100) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        x = values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z)
                              / diffTime * 10000;
        if (speed &gt; SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            // yes, this is a shake action! Do something about it!
                // if device is shake with threshold then this condition become true..
                // you can put your code here... 
        }
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
        }
    }
    }
}
```