# Detecting Significant Device Motion on Android

Tags: android, motion-detection, motionevent

I've been trying to figure out how to make an application that detects whether the device has been moved a significant amount, something more than just shakes. I am trying to detect a distance of, say, at least a foot. Reading the Training section on the official Android Development site, my best guess is that I should be using the [Significant Motion Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-significant), but I can't find an example of how to use it. Do I just store my "current" location in an array, and then compare that versus the `Event`'s values array whenever there is an `onTrigger()` is called?

Or should I be using the accelerometer instead? Some other sensor? The `LocationManager` (is that one accurate enough?)?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the Significant Motion Sensor [demo activity in ApiDemos](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/TriggerSensors.java), there isn't much to do. The triger sensor fires, contains no meaningful data in the [`values`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) field (it's an array with just one element, always 1.0 according to what I've tested) and disables itself.

So, there is nothing to actually compare with. The event fired, and that's it. You'll just have to trust that it matches your definition of "moved a significant amount" :/

If you want to measure a distance on the order of a foot, I'm pretty sure *Location* isn't precise enough (since it's GPS based at most).

As for *Accelerometer* data, you could theoretically, calculate distance from it (acceleration -> speed -> distance) but it's highly inaccurate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356253/82788), which basically claims it's not practical.

Comment: I'll play with it then, see if it's good enough for me. Or maybe somebody will show up a different solution before then.

Comment: Is it possible to detect motion in other way (and wakeup from sleep) ? I have mediatek device which has no "significant motion" sensor (according to sensors detect apk), yet, it has built in feature which turn on screen on movement. How can it be ?