# What are intended use cases for the SIGNIFICANT_MOTION sensor?

Tags: android

I'm running Google's [trigger sensor demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/c15585319ef524f9afeaf3c744987eed10a5df84/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/TriggerSensors.java) on a Samsung Galaxy S5. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-significant) and [AOSP notes](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#significant_motion) for the significant motion sensor don't provide much insight -- walking is mentioned but not by how much.

I've tried shaking my phone and walking around my house with it, and I can't get the event to trigger. I have been able to confirm that the sensor exists and the listener is being registered, so I'm pretty sure it's just not being triggered properly.

Is this sensor something that's useful to detect when a phone is picked up from a desk or jostled around in a purse, or is it more for when it's traveled several meters? Is the behavior consistent across phones?

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION), it's a wake up sensor.

Comment: Thanks @Strider, but that shouldn't mean the AP has to be asleep for it to trigger, does it?

Comment: That's correct, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#isWakeUpSensor%28%29)

Comment: and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/TriggerEvent.html) for the trigger, and a better explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567399/detecting-significant-device-motion-on-android)