# Accuracy of Accelerometer sensor provided by Android

Tags: android, position, accelerometer

I have to find out/track the position of a blind man moving in a mall. Can I use the accelerometer sensor provided by Android for the same ?

Is it reliable ? Any say about its accuracy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the accelerometer is not accurate enough, see my previous answer at [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970).

This question pops up surprisingly often, see for example [Distance moved by Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648538/341970) for a collection of similar questions.

Comment: So, is there any other algorithm to track indoor position, provided I don't have wifi and only a smart phone,

Comment: Yes, I link to them in my answer at [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970). I have no idea how well those algorithms would work in real life, I have never tried.