# measure distance travelled by iphone without using gps

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to find Distance using Gyro+Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647314/need-to-find-distance-using-gyroaccelerometer)
>   [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

I am developing an iOS app that measures the distance moved, for example, one could keep the iPhone in one's pocket after turning on the app, then should be able to get the distance he traveled by a vehicle that he is in, or if he is walking, running etc.I want it to be accurate enough so that one could move a device placed on a table, by say a feet, and the app tells you this small distance moved even. I do not want to use the GPS, but only the gyroscope and the accelerometer. What I have thought so far, is to get the angles by which the device has rotated along its three axes from the gyroscope and accelerometer data, periodically, and then use this info to figure out the magnitude of movement along the axis in which the user is moving, using the accelerometer. Does this look like a working approach? Also, are the in-built gyroscope and accelerometer accurate enough for this?

Comment: This is a classic question and sorry, but it won't work. :( See the link above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this can work, at least for a smaller distance.
Using GPS you woul dbe more successfull.

Whith accelerometer its is more  complex mathematics.
A remeber a scientific paper, but it is not to easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks Alex for replying back! I don't want to use the GPS for two reasons, one being that it will allow me to calculate the displacement, not the total distance travelled, as the user makes his way through the road (it will also fail if one tries measuring a person's height by moving the device vertically from feet to head), and secondly from the limited knowledge I have, it seems to me that GPS is very power hungry. I am ready to delve into complex maths, in case I do not see a simpler implementation for this case. I came across this recently http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~tmtong/kalman.php

Comment: The accelerator is hungry, too (GPS last 8hours, with dispaly disablled). Butgo for it, maybe finally you end up using both, GPS and Accelrometer, then you are the hero. (Vote up if you find my answer usefull)

Comment: When you got it to work, in some weeks, please post a comment, too.