# CMMotionactivitymanager authorizationstatus

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I want to get the authorization status for `CMMotionActivityManager`. For other services like calendar and location we have some property in the API that gives us the user authorization status for these classes. How i can get the authorization status for `CMMotionActivityManager` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - is Motion Activity Enabled in Settings > Privacy > Motion Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005990/ios-is-motion-activity-enabled-in-settings-privacy-motion-activity)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CMMotionActivityManager does not currently offer a way to check authorisation status directly like other frameworks.

[iOS - is Motion Activity Enabled in Settings > Privacy > Motion Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005990/ios-is-motion-activity-enabled-in-settings-privacy-motion-activity)

However, as the comments in the above question mention, if you attempt a query using

```
queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler
```

and the user has not authorised your application, the handler (CMMotionActivityQueryHandler) will return this error.

```
CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized
```

Comment: this will bring up the alert

Answer (score 11):

With introduction of IOS 11.* there is the possibility to call `CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus()` which gives you a detailed status.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'm doing it :

```
manager = CMMotionActivityManager()

let today = NSDate()

manager.queryActivityStartingFromDate(today, toDate: today, toQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
    withHandler: { (activities: [CMMotionActivity]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let error = error where error.code == Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.rawValue){
            print("NotAuthorized")
        }else {
            print("Authorized")
        }

})
```

Comment: Ok kids, remember to add manager.stopActivityUpdates() to the handler. :)

Comment: Good catch! Thank you

Comment: @CodeReaper I don't think that's necessary, is it? `manager.startActivityUpdates(to:withHandler:)` has not been called. `manager.queryActivityStarting(from:to:to:withHandler:)` is a one-shot request for motion data and doesn't continuously update.

Answer (score 3):

I had to adjust Zakaria's answer a bit for Swift 3.0 and also the new Error made problems, so I had to convert it back to NSError to get the code but this is how my function looks now. Thanks!

```
func triggerActivityPermissionRequest() {
  let manager = CMMotionActivityManager()
  let today = Date()

  manager.queryActivityStarting(from: today, to: today, to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (activities: [CMMotionActivity]?, error: Error?) -> () in
    if error != nil {
      let errorCode = (error! as NSError).code
      if errorCode == Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.rawValue) {
        print("NotAuthorized")
      }
    } else {
    print("Authorized")
  }
  manager.stopActivityUpdates()
  }) 
}
```