# CMMotionActivityManager callback when user not allow the permisson

Tags: ios, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I am using the following code from the Privacy Prompts project to get the Motion Permission.

```
- (void)requestMotionAccessData {
    self.cmManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    self.motionActivityQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [self.cmManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:self.motionActivityQueue withHandler:^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {
        /* 
         * Do something with the activity reported
         */

        NSLog(@"requestMotionAccessData");
        [self alertViewWithDataClass:Motion status:NSLocalizedString(@"ALLOWED", @"")];
        [self.cmManager stopActivityUpdates];
    }];
}
```

What if user not allow the motion permission. Do i get some callback?
If not is there an alternative way to get the this. I want the callback when user selects `Allow` or `Don't Allow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just can ... picking the error:

```
[stepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:[NSDate date]
                                     to:[NSDate date]
                                toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                            withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil && error.code == CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized) {
                                    // The app isn't authorized to use motion activity support.
}
```

from here: [iOS - is Motion Activity Enabled in Settings > Privacy > Motion Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21005990/1702413)