# How to check for type in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following code where I want to check for the type of error instance.

```
if let error = error {
    // error is Error
    if error is CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized {

    }                        
}
```

It is giving me error that `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized` is not a *type*. How can I check that if the error is of type `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Comment: `error` can never be `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized`, because `CMError` is not a Swift `Error`. Can you explain what you are trying to do? You should also provide some more code.

Comment: I am trying to check for pedometer error if the error is thrown due to unauthorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
if error as? CMError == CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized {
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: this gives an unrelated type warning

Answer (score 0):

You can either try [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmerror)

But CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized means that the app is not currently authorized to use motion activity support.
Required:
`var CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized: CMError { get }`

To learn more on this you can check **iOS - is Motion Activity Enabled in Settings > Privacy > Motion Activity** on **Stackoverflow** , here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005990/ios-is-motion-activity-enabled-in-settings-privacy-motion-activity)