# Is it possible to detect vertical movement (only up and down) with Android Sensors?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-sensors

I almost read every single question here about vertical movement but I couldnt get an exact conclusion and idea. Because most of the questions are about game programming where a lot of noise, rotation etc are involved like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863362/detect-horizontal-and-vertical-movement-of-the-smartphone-on-a-table) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201788/vertical-movement-sensor).

My question is quite simple. I only want to detect up and down movement (true or false, no measurement). I don't care about if portrait or landscape mode or rotation. I only want to know if user is moving phone up or down. For example;
I want to detect pull up movement. I put my phone in my pocket and do pull ups. Is it even possible? How accurate can it be and which sensors should I concentrate on?

Comment: This should be entirely achievable using the accelerometer. Just check if it gives alternating values. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried accelerometer only but I cant understand the changes of Y axis (I believe this is the one I need to concentrate on), Change is very minimal and sometimes goes minus, sometimes up. quite wavy. I thought that I need to combine with gravity somehow, no?

Comment: using accelerometer you can determine the linear acceleration in any specific axes, i.e in X,Y and Z axes

Comment: @batmaci Don't care about which axis it is, since the person could hold the phone any way. Look for acceleration in any axis, and count a change as 1 rep. And take the absolute change (using `Math.abs`) so you dont need to deal with negative numbers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Is it even more accurate the use Linear accelerometer? I read that it reduces noise from accelerometer and you get more accurate change

Comment: @batmaci Never used it, only the accelerometer.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the X,Y,Z acceleration data on a graph whilst doing pullups? 
If there is a clear pattern or spikes in the data then you can make an app that detects that pattern/ acceleration impulse (in any axis).

Comment: @AaronThompson Indeed i did and I couldnt any conclusion because my problem was I wasnt sure which change was up or down. because I cant count every change as 1 rep like Carcigenicate said. It should be only Up movement is 1 rep. I will try it again and update my question with some values of changes on axises

Answer (score 2):

This is actually much more difficult than you might suppose.

The phone's gyroscope sensors give you the movement of the phone *with respect to the phone*, not the world.  Leaving the phone face-up, flat on the table would give you

- `x = 0.0`,
- `y = 0.0`,
- `z = -9.8`.

These values would be fluctuating slightly due to the sensors.  As the phone rotates, these base (at rest) values change - at 45 degrees you get

- `x = 6.93`,
- `y = 0`,
- `z = 6.93`,

so that `sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z) = 9.8`.  If you want to isolate up-down movement, you either have to stop the phone rotating, or ignore this movement.

If you stop the phone rotating - e.g. phone must be held upright in pocket, then you can just look at the `x` component which will, at rest, read `-9.81` and changes will show *acceleration*, less-negative or positive being in an upward direction, more-negative in a downward direction.

If you wish to ignore other movement (e.g. user only uses this for defined activities), then the absolute value will do.  `sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` will give you `9.8` at rest and changes to that value will be due to acceleration of the device.  A bit of maths later (brute-force numerical integration) and you can have speed or distance travelled (although note that this get very inaccurate very quickly...)

Note there is a [Rotation Vector Sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate) API that may allow you to remove the device's orientation from the gyroscope readings allowing you to calculate the real-world movement, however I haven't tried this API and do not know what extra hardware (if any) is needed.