# Projected travelled distance from gyroscope / accelerometer measurements

Tags: position, accelerometer, physics, distance, gyroscope

I want to build an app that calculates project distance traveled by a kicked ball (ball is kicked into a training net) based on the initial readings from accelerometer/gyroscope and some assumptions about weight, air resistance, etc. The ball contains Triple Axis Accelerometer and Gyro. The measurements can either be raw accel/gyro x/y/z values or one of the following:

- Actual quaternion components in a [w, x, y, z] format
- Euler angles (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions
- yaw/pitch/roll angles (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions acceleration components with gravity removed. This acceleration reference frame is not compensated for orientation, so +X is always +X according to the sensor, just without the effects of gravity.
- acceleration components with gravity removed and adjusted for the world frame of reference (yaw is relative to initial orientation)

I actually don't know what any of the above means.

Could someone suggest a formula to use in this scenario with this kind of data available? I went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647314/need-to-find-distance-using-gyroaccelerometer), but it doesn't exactly have what I'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to find Distance using Gyro+Accelerometer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647314/need-to-find-distance-using-gyroaccelerometer)

Comment: I did mention that question in my response. It is possible using a model.